# Why does post request work locally and not remotely? url searched for is different

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url, express

I have a page with buttons at a specific url. here they are locally and remotly

local : `http://localhost:4000/individual/comp6/57d614b711d268030080eda9/`

remote : `https://linknon.herokuapp.com/individual/comp6/57d614b711d268030080eda9/` (THIS IS NOT MY REAL LINK)

when I click on the button and have `app.post("/individual/"+ comp + "/usefulness", postHandler)` in my code, localhost works (the db get updated)

but when I go on line and click on the button I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` it could not get `https://linknon.herokuapp.com/individual/comp6/57d614b711d268030080eda9/usefulness` .I found that to be weird . **Why did it work on local and not remote**?

my `app.post("/individual/"+ comp + "/usefulness", postHandler)` doesnt include the id after the company name (the company name is the comp var). I'm assuming that for remote I had to add in Id for some reason. I tried something like using regular expression (never did that b4) `app.post("/individual/.+/usefulness", postHandler)` did not work on local and wondering if it would work on remote.

I also do post requests in the same module like this

```
app.post("/usefulness", postHandler);
app.post("/reviewfor/usefulness", postHandler);
```

those seem to work

I feel like they all have in common `usefulness` at the end so maybe a regular expression would work.

Comment: https://linknon.herokuapp.com/individual/comp6/57d614b711d268030080eda9/usefulness is surely 404

Comment: I didnt show the real link. I don't want to show my private work. I was just showing what the link looks like. It's the post request that's the problem not the get.

Comment: Ok, can you send a successful post request using curl/postman? How do you know the thing works?

Comment: **is this what you want?** curl 'http://localhost:4000/individual/comp5/usefulness' -X POST -H 'Host: localhost:4000' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:4000/individual/comp5/57d614b711d268030080eda9' -H 'Content-Length: 131' -H 'Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AUuwMOeFPZs-IArTrzyQBTYi9jId0B1S0.Ehdq%2FbW5MbHLNtfeu0iJpoACpK50oDhTo4wCMbRvbOQ'

Comment: I right clicked the post request and clicked "copy as curl" in FF firebug and I pasted it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem. Don't use variables this way when defining routes:

`app.post("/individual/"+ comp + "/usefulness", postHandler)`

It mixes up app-load-time variables (`comp` in this case) with what should be per-request variables. Express handles per-request variables with route parameters. So you need something like:

`app.post("/individual/:comp/usefulness", postHandler)`

Then in the body of `postHandler` you can access `req.params.comp` which will be the specific value from the URL on this request like `comp1`, `comp2`, `comp3` etc.